# Adding 'key' before each object in array in recursive tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json which has a hierarchial tree structure which may have 'n ' number of nesting. I need to convert the below Input json to Output JSON format i am adding only one level of nesting real time it may have n level of nesting.

Input JSON :

```
[
{
"name": "CompanyI",
"expenses": 105000,
"employees": 22,
"contact": "Makenzie Higgs",
"children": [
  {
    "name": "Group bet",
    "expenses": 1000,
    "employees": 6,
    "contact": "Camila Devonport"
  },
  {
    "name": "Group gamma",
    "expenses": 40000,
    "employees": 4,
    "contact": "Violet Curtis",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Child 1",
        "expense": 300,
        "employees": 3,
        "contact": "Child Level 1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Child 2",
        "expense": 400,
        "employees": 55,
        "contact": "Child Level 2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Child 3",
        "expense": 500,
        "employees": 44,
        "contact": "Child Level 3"
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
 }
```

]

I have tried the below code but it does not work recursive

Code:

Output JSON :

```
[
 {
 "data": {
  "name": "Company I",
  "expenses": 105000,
  "employees": 22,
  "contact": "Makenzie Higgs"
},
"children": [
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "Group beta",
      "expenses": 10000,
      "employees": 6,
      "contact": "Camila Devonport"
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "name": "Group gamma",
      "expenses": 40000,
      "employees": 4,
      "contact": "Violet Curtis"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "Child 1",
          "expense": 300,
          "employees": 3,
          "contact": "Child Level 1"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "Child 2",
          "expense": 400,
          "employees": 55,
          "contact": "Child Level 2"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "name": "Child 3",
          "expense": 500,
          "employees": 44,
          "contact": "Child Level 3"
         }
        }
      ]
     }
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: dont understand your goal please be more precise : what about the key ? do you want to ass a key that reflects the hierarchy and then flaten the object ?

Comment: @PhilMaGeo i am trying to acheive a tree structure  using the https://constantin.software/cp-react-tree-table/docs/ i am trying to convert my data to the above defined format.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `forEach` loop

```js
var obj=[
  {
    "name": "CompanyI",
    "expenses": 105000,
    "employees": 22,
    "contact": "Makenzie Higgs",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Group bet",
        "expenses": 1000,
        "employees": 6,
        "contact": "Camila Devonport"
      },
      {
        "name": "Group gamma",
        "expenses": 40000,
        "employees": 4,
        "contact": "Violet Curtis"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "CompanyI",
    "expenses": 105000,
    "employees": 22,
    "contact": "Makenzie Higgs",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Group bet",
        "expenses": 1000,
        "employees": 6,
        "contact": "Camila Devonport"
      },
      {
        "name": "Group gamma",
        "expenses": 40000,
        "employees": 4,
        "contact": "Violet Curtis"
      }
    ]
  }
]
obj.forEach(function(e,i){
obj[i]={data:e}
obj[i].children=[];
obj[i].data.children.forEach(function(x,y){
obj[i].children.push({data:x})
})
delete obj[i].data.children
})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: the data is converting but the first level is not enclosed with in braces you can verify me original ouptut JSON

Comment: it works but works for only one level, since it is hierarchy structure there may be 'n' level doesn't work for multi level.

Comment: Works in the snippet for multiple entries too. And don't just give preliminary inputs. Provide the exact input for which you need the solution

Comment: i have updated the input and output format above with nested structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

Basically, I have created two functions, one to handle array and one handle object, Which calls itself recursively and creates the final object.

```js
let dataArray = [
  {
    "name": "CompanyI",
    "expenses": 105000,
    "employees": 22,
    "contact": "Makenzie Higgs",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Group bet",
        "expenses": 1000,
        "employees": 6,
        "contact": "Camila Devonport"
      },
      {
        "name": "Group gamma",
        "expenses": 40000,
        "employees": 4,
        "contact": "Violet Curtis"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function convert(x){
 let obj = {};
 for(let attr in x){
  if(Array.isArray(x[attr])){
    obj[attr] = convertArray(x[attr]);
  } else {
    obj[attr] = x[attr];
  }
 }
 return obj;
}

function convertArray(array){
  return array.map(obj=>({data:convert(obj)}));
}

console.log(convertArray(dataArray));
```

Comment: the data is converting but the first level is not enclosed with in braces you can verify me original ouptut JSON which i included